# Why embed dimemsion must be divisible by num of heads in MultiheadAttention?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, transformer-model, attention-model

I am learning the Transformer. Here is the pytorch document for [MultiheadAttention](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html#torch.nn.MultiheadAttention). In their [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/7a178a8a523d4653a3a2fa10c573b71e7fab1b9a/torch/nn/modules/activation.py#L874), I saw there is a constraint:

```
 assert self.head_dim * num_heads == self.embed_dim, "embed_dim must be divisible by num_heads"
```

Why require the constraint: `embed_dim must be divisible by num_heads?`  If we go back to the equation

[image: MultiHead(Q,K,V)=Concat(head1​,…,headh​)WOwhereheadi​=Attention(QWiQ​,KWiK​,VWiV​)]

Assume:
`Q`, `K`,`V` are `n x emded_dim` matrices; all the weight matrices `W` is `emded_dim x head_dim`,

Then, the concat `[head_i, ..., head_h]` will be a `n x (num_heads*head_dim)` matrix;

`W^O` with size `(num_heads*head_dim) x embed_dim`

`[head_i, ..., head_h] * W^O` will become a `n x embed_dim` output

I don't know why we require `embed_dim must be divisible by num_heads`.

Let say we have `num_heads=10000`, the resuts are the same, since the matrix-matrix product will absort this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I understood, it is a simplification they have added to keep things simple. Theoretically, we can implement the model like you proposed (similar to the original paper).
In [pytorch documention](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html), they have briefly mentioned it.

```
Note that `embed_dim` will be split across `num_heads` (i.e. each head will have dimension `embed_dim` // `num_heads`)
```

Also, if you see the Pytorch implementation, you can see it is a bit different (optimised in my point of view) when comparing to the originally proposed model. For example, they use `MatMul` instead of `Linear` and `Concat` layer is ignored. Refer the below which shows the first encoder (with Btach size 32, 10 words, 512 features).

[image]

P.s:
If you need to see the model params (like the above image), this is the code I used.

```
import torch
transformer_model = torch.nn.Transformer(d_model=512, nhead=8, num_encoder_layers=1,num_decoder_layers=1,dim_feedforward=11)  # change params as necessary
tgt = torch.rand((20, 32, 512))
src = torch.rand((11, 32, 512))
torch.onnx.export(transformer_model, (src, tgt), "transformer_model.onnx")
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a sequence of `seq_len x emb_dim` (ie. `20 x 8`) and you want to use `num_heads=2`, the sequence will be split along the `emb_dim` dimension. Therefore you get two `20 x 4` sequences. You want every head to have the same shape and if `emb_dim` isn't divisible by `num_heads` this wont work. Take for example a sequence `20 x 9` and again `num_heads=2`. Then you would get `20 x 4` and `20 x 5` which are not the same dimension.

Comment: Good example, if `seq_len x emb_dim` is `20 x 9`, and `num_heads=2`, let choose `head_dim=77`, then we can get the `head_i` is a `20  x 144` matrix. as such `[head_1, head_2]` is `20 x 288`,   We can still chose `W^O` is `288 x 9`. we can still get the final `20 x 9`. My point is that we can also map `emb_dim` into any lenght, and use `W^O` to project it back to `emb_dim`. Why need to dive `emb_dim` into even length? Thanks.